# Ruby Background Scheduler

Tags: ruby, cron, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq, resque-scheduler

i'm trying to use some background scheduling in ruby, and seems like havent found yet the right solution.
so many gem are talked about on the net, rufus, sidekiq, resque, whenever , clockwwork , but i was wondering what is the best option for our need.

basically i have few jobs that i want to schedule on a cron basis upfront.
also, would like to have the ability to update those jobs, or add new jobs during runtime.
tried the following:

- rufus-scheduler : was vary simple and easy to integrate. had the ability to schedule jobs by ons startup. the problem is there is no ability to dynamically integreate with it during runtime.
- resque - should have the ability to schedule at runtime (schedule.yml) and also to integrate with dynamically, but uses process for each worker. bad performance.
- sidekiq - should have support all of these. but by adding also some 3rd party gem "sidekiq-scheduler". had few issues on the scheduler and looks like its not really supported, which might be an issue.

so should we keep invest on the sidekiq-scheduler or have we missed some more mature gem that could help us making this works?

any help will be appriciated.

Levi

Comment: We use sidekiq and the whenever gem extensively - they wok great.  That said, this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: I agree with @Anthony here. There is not really a right or wrong answer here. It really depends on your requirements. Some gems have dependencies like redis, others don't. Some there's also differences in memory footprint, scalability and thread-safety requirements. I like the idea of ActiveJob that abstracts background job processing and allows you to switch backends easily.

Comment: There's also [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq). `sidekiq-scheduler` hasn't been updated in a while, I think `whenever` is most common now.